# debug javascript and see what's being sent to webassembly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, reverse-engineering, webassembly

There is this website that uses a webassembly file to create a hash.

I have already found out that it's using some of the inputs and combine them to create an sha256 hash.

I need to understand what is the right combination.

I tried debugging it with chrome devtools but it has 27,000 lines of js code (obfuscated) and it's really hard to find the point that I'm looking for.
I also tried to decompile wasm to c with an online tools but it wasn't successful.

I'm not asking to find this for me, just tell me what options do I have to make this possible or maybe there's some trick for debugging/reverse engineering this kind of code.

Comment: Message me on Reddit at reddit.com/u/GirkovArpa and I'll help you out with this.

Comment: @GirkovArpa I gave up on that approach and now I'm using that wasm file to do the same process in my code